# Evaluating a line integral over a border of a 3D space

Tags: differential-forms, parametrization, line-integrals

I am given a differential form $$\omega = (y^2+z^2)dx + (z^2+x^2)dy + (x^2+y^2)dz$$ and I have to evaluate the integral $\int_\gamma \omega$ on the border of the set $$\gamma=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3} : x^2+y^2+z^2=2Rx ,\quad x^2+y^2 = 2rx, \quad z>0\}$$
going only once clockwise.

I think I am no able to find a parametrization of the border using only one variable, because parameterizing the cylinder I obtained $$\cases{x=r+r\cos\theta \\y=r\sin\theta\\z=z}$$
with $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$. Substituting this into the sphere I have
$$z^2 = 2Rr(1+\cos\theta)-2R^2-2r^2\cos\theta$$ and given that z is positive $$z = \sqrt{2Rr(1+\cos\theta)-2R^2-2r^2\cos\theta}.$$ So I have $r(\theta) =(r+r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, \sqrt{2Rr(1+\cos\theta)-2R^2-2r^2\cos\theta)}$ and this seems incorrect to me because then I am not able to proceed with the integral.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: $\gamma$ as you have it is not a curve but a surface. I would suspect an error in the problem—the $\le$ seems inappropriate here.

Comment: You're right. So, I edited: instead of $x^2+y^2\le2rx$, let's suppose that there is: $x^2+y^2=2rx$. How does it change?

Comment: Now the intersection is a curve that *can* be singly-parameterized.